# Assigning values to array: memset vs for loop

Tags: c++11, memset

Currently, I am facing problem in between `memset` and for loop while I am trying to assign values to an array. The output of my program is different when I tried to replace `memset` with for loop. When I tried `memset` I got output as `5`

```
bool visited[21][21]; int ans[21][21];
memset(ans,10000,sizeof(ans));
 memset(visited,0,sizeof(visited));
```

but when I tried to replace `memset` with for loop I got output as `-1`

```
bool visited[21][21]; int ans[21][21];
for(int a1=0;a1<21;a1++)
    {
        for(int b1=0;b1<21;b1++)
        {
            ans[a1][b1]=10000;
        }
    }


    for(int a1=0;a1<21;a1++)
    {
        for(int b1=0;b1<21;b1++)
        {
            visited[a1][b1]=0;
        }
    }
```

Here `memset` gives correct output but for loop is not.Can anyone explain me the reason of this Or the way to replace `memset` by for loop?

Here is my full code with input

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std ;

bool ar[21][21]; bool visited[21][21]; int ans[21][21]; int xa[]={0,-1,0,1}; int yb[]={1,0,-1,0}; int n;


typedef struct Point{ int x,y;
}P;

typedef struct C { int x,y; int dis; } C;

bool issafe(int x,int y) { return (x>=0 && x<n && y>=0 && y<n && ar[x][y] && !visited[x][y]); }

void bfs(int x,int y) { queue<C> q; C in; in.x=x; in.y=y; in.dis=0; q.push(in); visited[x][y]=1;

while(!q.empty())
{
    C c=q.front();
    q.pop();
    int a=c.x;
    int b=c.y;
    int d=c.dis;
    ans[a][b]=d;

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {

        int nx=a+xa[i];
        int ny=b+yb[i];
        if(issafe(nx,ny))
        {
            visited[nx][ny]=1;
            in.x=nx;
            in.y=ny;
            in.dis=d+1;
            q.push(in);
        }
 }

}
}

int main() {

cin>>n;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        cin>>ar[i][j];
    }
}

int q;
cin>>q;

P rare[q];

int fans=10000;
int mx=-1;


for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
{

    int a,b;
    cin>>a>>b;

    rare[i].x=a;
    rare[i].y=b;
}


for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
       for(int k=0;k<21;k++){
                for(int m=0;m<21;m++){
            ans[k][m]=10000;
                }
            }
  // memset(ans,10000,sizeof(ans));

        int flag=0;
        for(int l=0;l<21;l++)
       {
           for(int n1=0;n1<21;n1++){
        visited[l][n1]=0;
           }
        }
       // memset(visited,0,sizeof(visited));



        mx=-1;
        if(ar[i][j])
        {
            bfs(i,j);
            for(int k=0;k<q;k++)
            {
                if(ans[rare[k].x][rare[k].y]==10000)
                {
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!flag)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<q;k++)
                {
                    mx=max(mx,ans[rare[k].x][rare[k].y]);
                   // cout<<mx<<endl;
                }
            }
          //  cout<< mx<<fans<<endl;
            fans=min(fans,mx);
        }
    }
}

cout<<fans<<endl;
}
/* input
8
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3
0 2
1 7
4 7
*/
```

Comment: `int ans[21][21]` does not create a single array of 21*21, instead it creates 21 arrays that are 21 long.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memset not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707820/memset-not-working)

Comment: My memset gives correct output but for lopp is not. @Mgetz

Comment: The code you presented doesn't output anything.

Comment: I have edited my question with code @Ruslan

Comment: Could you make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I doubt many will go through all the code to debug it for you. I suppose it has at least two bugs, which lead you to thinking that `memset` works as intended while it doesn't with the value of `10000`.

Comment: Don't use `memset`, don't use built-in arrays, and avoid using a loop. If `std::fill_n` does not produce correct results, then that means you're doing something wrong. Which is the reason why you shouldn't use `memset` or a manual loop, since they often hide the fact that you're doing something wrong. Change your code to use `std::array` instead of built-in arrays, then use `std::fill_n`, and take it from there. This will make it somewhat easier to have a correct implementation in a natural way.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `memset` in C++, [it is error-prone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707820/memset-not-working), as you just discovered.

Fixes:

```
bool visited[21][21] = {}; // zero-initialize

int ans[21][21]; // uninitialized
std::fill_n(*ans, sizeof ans / sizeof **ans, 10000);
```

Comment: I understand your point. But the problem is using `memset` I am getting right output. Not by for loop or `fill_n`

Comment: @Yonex You cannot possibly get correct output for `memset(..., 10000, ...)`, no. Unless your definition of correct is incorrect.